# How do I use the python requests package to POST a .csv file, from within a .zip folder, using form-data and a parameters file?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, postman

I am currently attempting to replicate a manual API call I have made in POSTMAN via Python.

I am **POST**ing a .csv file from within a .zip folder. To do so, I have to use **form-data** within the **body** of the request, add the *inputFile* with the *value* being the file itself and the *Content-Type: application/zip.* I also have a file for the parameters, which is **JSON** (*see attached*).

[POSTMAN Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC5Hr.png)

I have tried a couple of different methods to **POST** the data, but I am primarily receiving 415 (unsupported media) response. Now, when I was doing this via POSTMAN, I did get this error a couple of times when the parameters file or the zip file *Content-Type* wasn't properly specified.

```
import requests
import boto3

import_headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>',
                  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                  'Accept': '*/*',
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token}
test_file = open(r'C:\{filePath}\test_undelimited_MKII.zip', 'rb')
params_file = open(r'C:\{filePath}\paremeters.json', 'rb')
params_obj = {
  "mode" : "CREATE_UPDATE",
  "encoding" : "UTF-8",
  "format" : {
    "separator" : ";",
    "endOfLine" : "\r\n",
    "enclosing" : "\"",
    "escaping" : "\""
  },
  "reportRecipients": [
    {emailAddress}
  ]
}

requests.post(url, headers=import_headers, params={"archive": ("paremeters.json", params_file)}, files={"archive": ("test_undelimited_MKII.zip", test_file)})

requests.post(url, headers=import_headers, params=params_obj, files={"archive": ("test_undelimited_MKII.zip", test_file)})
```

**N.B.** I am relatively new to Python, so be gentle, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making a multipart/form-data request with a file upload using the requests library in Python, you need to construct the request properly to ensure that the file and parameters are sent correctly. Here's some example of how you can modify your code to make the API call:

```
enter code here
```

```
import requests

url = "<API_URL>"
access_token = "<ACCESS_TOKEN>"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}

files = [
    ("archive", ("test_undelimited_MKII.zip", open(r"C:\{filePath}\test_undelimited_MKII.zip", "rb"), "application/zip")),
    ("params", ("parameters.json", open(r"C:\{filePath}\parameters.json", "rb"), "application/json"))
]

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked lovely. Note: taking out the Content-Type from my headers was the clincher, I think having that AND having the api call being a multipart/form-data was messing things up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For a request like the one in your Postman screenshot, you'll want two `files`:

```
import requests

with open(r"C:\{filePath}\test_undelimited_MKII.zip", "rb") as test_file, open(r"C:\{filePath}\paremeters.json", "rb") as params_file:
    requests.post(
        url,
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        },
        files={
            "parameters": ("paremeters.json", params_file),
            "archive": ("test_undelimited_MKII.zip", test_file),
        },
    )
```